# getting data from API with useFetch. How to destructure to get meta and data objects and extend Respone type to include

Tags: nuxtjs3

Learning Nuxt3 and first time using fetch as opposed to Axios.

I have an API that returns data with 'meta' object and 'data' array.

Fetch expects response to only include a single 'data' object with everything in it. The Response type doesn't include a 'data' prop.

Here is a simple example:

```
    const { data, error, pending, refresh } = await useAPIFetch<Response>(
   "/matters",
   {
   method: "GET",

  params: {
    search: "",
    list: "",
   },
  }
 );

const matters = data.data
```

I want to set matters to just get the data.data array. However, I get a type error

Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Ref<Response | null>'

How do I extend the Response type to include meta and data types? Or is there another way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own interface and extend it to the `response` interface. Something like this example.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">

interface Meta {
  obj1: string
  obj2: string
}

interface Data {
  data: string[]
}

interface CustomResponse extends Response {
  meta: Meta
  data: string[]
}

const { data: response } = await useFetch<CustomResponse>('/api/your-api')

</script>
```

By following that, it should be working for you as well. See screenshots as proof.
[image]

Meta interface
[image]

As for the Data. When you try to `map` or `push` It should be suggested as they are for arrays.
[image]